# Can Lint resolve the include path of Header Files

Tags: c, header-files, lint, pc-lint

I have setup one Project Folder in which i have main Project Directory, say `Main_Proj`. In that folder, I have created two folders for `Header_Files` and `Source_Files`.

Folder `Header_Files` only contains all header files. lets say `module_1a.h` and so on. Whereas, folder `Source_Files` contains `main.c` and again module wise folders, lets say `Module_1` which only contains required `.c` files of particular module. So for example, folder `Module_1` contains `Module_1a.c` and `Module_1b.c`.

So the path for `Module_1a.c` would be =

> Main_proj\Souce_Files\Module_1\Module_1a.c

and in all source file I have included the Header Files like below -

```
//Code for Module_1a.c
#include "..\..\Header_Files\Module_1a.h"
....
```

My IDE is **MP LAB** and this code and all modules are working fine with **MP LAB xc8 compiler**.

Problem occurs when i started `Lint`ing my code, its giving me error like -

> Error 322: Unable to open include file
>   '....\Header_Files\Module_1a.h'

I am using **PC Lint for C and C++ (version 9)**. I searched for resolution of this error in Regference manual and got to know to include that directory with `-i` option.

I also checked with `set INCLUDE=<directory Path>` but its not working.

Is there any thing i can do with my std.lnt file or do i have to change the folder structure for my Project?

Comment: Since the problematic include has a relative reference, it might matter what directory lint is started from, or at least some way to tell it where to assume it is starting from.

Comment: "-i" should work. Post your directory and root direcory strucure. 
(You can also work with absolute paths, but this is not easy portable)
Lint is in the standard directory C\lint?

Comment: @Miguel13366 : Yes, with absolute path Lint is working fine, but to replace all includes with their absolute path would take lot of rework. Lint is in the C directory. I am keeping my Project Folder in Desktop, and i am including this path in std.lnt as follows - 
-i"C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Main_Proj\Header_Files\"

Comment: Maybee hou have the problem with adding the path before your filename
#include "Header_Files\header.h" and lint searches in Headerfiles\Headerfiles\ 
You can work with FIND and print all c and h-Files into a txt File, so you can copy them into your lint file.
Your std.lnt is in "C\lint" or somewhere under "C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Main_Proj\" ? 
Normally I have a lint-directory in the project with the config files and paths are relative from this directory.

Answer (score 1):

Any source code tree organization where headers or paths contain `..` is broken as designed.

The way to go and do away with a lot of problems is

- have a single project root directory
- Use `-I.` when compiling, linting, preprocessing, static analyzing, ...
- all file references in headers and the project makefile are as seen from the project root

I.e. a header includes other headers using

```
#include "subdir/whatever/foo_module.h"
```

and all compilation happens with the working directory being the project root, e.g.

```
subdir/whatever/foo_module.o: subdir/whatever/foo_module.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I. -o $@ $<
```

This keeps `-I` lists extremely short; ideally only `-I.`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the flag

`+fdi // #include search in the directory of the including file`

see Error 322 at https://www.kessler.de/prd/gimpel/pclint-meldungen.htm

or

https://www.bezem.de/pdf/htwpl.pdf

or

https://www.gimpel.com/archive/pub90/read90.txt (Section Microsoft's nested #include search)